# Can't eject USB drive without sudo?

Tags: usb, mount, sudo, udev, unmount

I'm trying to eject a USB drive in the command line with `eject /dev/sdg1` but I get the following error:

```
eject: unable to open `/dev/sdg'
```

The command unmounts the drive but does not eject it. However, running with sudo works just fine. Is this a bug or expected behavior? I'm trying to incorporate this into a python application so sudo isn't really an option. Note that `umount` works just fine without sudo.

This is a usb flash drive. I think there's only a single partition on it

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! What type of device is /dev/sdg? eject is specifically for removeable media such as Optical, Floppy, tape, ZIP, JAZ drives and is not supported by all devices. Further /dev/sdg1 indicates a partition, not a device.

Comment: @ElderGeek this is a usb flash drive. I think there's only a single partition on it

Comment: As described by @ElderGeek, *it is 'enough' to unmount all mounted partitions on a USB drive to be able to unplug it safely*. This does not turn off the power, and it can be mounted again. This is what I have been doing for years and it works well. - I think 'ejecting' in the case of USB drives means unmounting *and* poweroff, as implemented by some GUI tools (with the eject symbol). In this case it is not straight-forward to mount it again without unplugging and replugging. Is this what you want?

Comment: @sudodus yes, that is what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no mechanism for ejecting a USB device. Unmount it with (in your case `umount /dev/sdg1` and manually remove it. (Assuming /dev/sdg1 is the only mounted partition on /dev/sdg). You can verify what partitions are mounted on a device with commands like `lsblk` and `mount | grep sdX` where sdX corresponds to your device (in your case sdg).

`eject` is specifically for removeable media such as Optical, Floppy, tape, ZIP, JAZ drives and is not supported by flash drives at all.

Sources:

`man eject`

Comment: Alright thanks. Just confused since sudo does properly eject the usb. I’ll just use unmount

Answer (score 4):

I think 'ejecting' in the case of USB drives means unmounting and poweroff, as implemented by some GUI tools (with the eject symbol).

You can look into **`udisks`** and the tool **`udisksctl`**.

Read the manuals

```
man udisks
man udisksctl
```

For example, you will find the commands

```
   udisksctl mount {--object-path OBJECT | --block-device DEVICE}
             [--filesystem-type TYPE] [--options OPTIONS...]
             [--no-user-interaction]

   udisksctl unmount {--object-path OBJECT | --block-device DEVICE} [--force]
             [--no-user-interaction]

   udisksctl power-off {--object-path OBJECT | --block-device DEVICE}
             [--no-user-interaction]
```

I think the

```
udisksctl unmount --block-device <device> && \
udisksctl power-off --block-device <device>
```

commands can do what you want. In this case with one partition in 'sdg' `<device>` is `/dev/sdg1`

> ```
>    power-off
>        Arranges for the drive to be safely removed and powered off. On the OS
>        side this includes ensuring that no process is using the drive, then
>        requesting that in-flight buffers and caches are committed to stable
>        storage. The exact steps for powering off the drive depends on the
>        drive itself and the interconnect used. For drives connected through
>        USB, the effect is that the USB device will be deconfigured followed by
>        disabling the upstream hub port it is connected to.
>
>        Note that as some physical devices contain multiple drives (for example
>        4-in-1 flash card reader USB devices) powering off one drive may affect
>        other drives. As such there are not a lot of guarantees associated with
>        performing this action. Usually the effect is that the drive disappears
>        as if it was unplugged.
> ```